# Customize messages on Symfony2 Admin Generator

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, admin-generator

I have my admin generator on Symfony 2.6 and i need to customize the messages, principally the error message on delete option.

Actually I have done things like:

```
delete:
    params:
        messages:
            error: The object cludn't be deleted.
```

How can I customize the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to override the translation in `AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle/Resources/translations/Admingenerator.en.yml` by adding the new message in directory `app/Resources/translations`

[Source](https://github.com/symfony2admingenerator/AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle/blob/master/Resources/translations/Admingenerator.en.yml)

[Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#translations)